# Uninstall module for which an update is pending?

Tags: 7, drush, installation

I have a module for which an update is pending (drush updatedb). Unfortunately the update fails, blocking other updates of course (since it seems impossible to update selectively).

Is it safe to I pm-uninstall the module? Will this automatically delete the pending update? Or do I risk ending up in an even worse limbo?

[ As noted in the comments, taking a database dump and then restoring if anything goes wrong is an option; I'm still curious if there is a general rule about uninstalling while db updates are pending) ]

(BTW the module is service_links)

Comment: What happens when you try it? Do you get errors? I'm struggling to understand the motivation for asking this, surely trying it yourself would have been far quicker than asking here?

Comment: Because I might get in an even worse state if the uninstall fails, or if it seemingly succeeds but then completely blocks future updatedb's? I'm struggling to understand the motivation for asking a question with such an obvious answer :)

Comment: @dan3 I'm struggling to work out why you would post something so rude to someone trying to help. I'd suggest taking a database dump, and then running the uninstall. If it does anything funky, you can just restore the database.

Comment: My comment was an exact mirror of the one I replied to, wasn't it? I could do the dump, thanks -- however I'm still curious about the general principle (if there is a general principle)

Comment: So lots of struggling going on here :) @Chapabu I didn't take that as being rude; it had a smiley which in my world means it's to be taken nicely! Dan, you should have a test environment set up (and don't talk to me about resources, any developer in the world ***should*** have a disposable dev copy of their project :P) That's what you would use to answer the question yourself, in a matter of seconds. To the _principle_...As soon as you uninstall the module, it's inactive in the system table, and its install file will _not_ be queried for update functions when the time comes. Hope that helps

Comment: @Clive, if you want me to accept your answer, you might want to make it an answer :)

Comment: Go with Greg's answer, looks like I over-simplified things ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slight correction to Clive's comment above: as soon as you disable the module, it is inactive in the system tables. When you uninstall it, all of its data is erased from the database. The fact that a module has pending updates won't affect the operation of disabling or uninstalling it, but beware of re-enabling a module that has been disabled for a period of time.  For way too much information on this subject, see: https://drupal.org/node/1199946

Comment: So I guess once you disable you might as well uninstall; which is what I was planning to do anyway